# ng-Click not firing even tho it's in the same scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I searched through the forum but I didnt find an answer to this question. I want to set the value of my input field to the geolocated Address after button click but the ng-Click="locate()" is not firing. Here is my HTML:

```
<script id="templates/search.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Datenerfassung">
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="DataCtrl">
        <div class="list">

          <!-- Adressen Input Feld -->
           <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
             <span class="input-label">Startpunkt in Adressform</span>
             <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Startpunkt in Adressform">
             <button id="curr_loc" class="button button-balanced" ng-Click="locate()">this-one-doesnt-fire</button>
           </label>

           <!-- Zeit Input Feld -->
           <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
             <span class="input-label">Zeit in Minuten</span>
             <input id="time" type="number" placeholder="Zeit in Minuten">
           </label>
        </div>
        <!-- Fortbewegungsmittel Toggle Liste -->
        <div class="item item-divider">
          Mit welchem Fortbewegungsmittel </br>
          möchten Sie die Umgebung erkunden?
        </div>

        <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.move" value="walk">Zu Fuß</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.move" value="transit">Tram</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.move" value="car">Auto</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.move" value="bike">Fahrrad</ion-radio>

        <!-- Button zum loslegen -->
        <button id="erkunden" ui-sref="map" class="button button-balanced" ng-Click="setData()">Erkunden</button>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab ui-sref="home" title="Home" icon="ion-home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ui-sref="faq" title="FAQ" icon="ion-help-circled"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ui-sref="about" title="About" icon="ion-information-circled"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ui-sref="impressum" title="Impressum" icon="ion-clipboard"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
    </ion-view>
 </script>
```

And my contoller looks like this:

```
mapApp.controller("DataCtrl", function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.setData = function() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var move = $scope.move;
    dataService.setData(address,time,move);
  };

  $scope.locate = function() {
    console.log("asd");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            console.log(pos);
            document.getElementById("address").value = pos[0] + "," + pos[1];
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Like I said, clicking on the button is not triggering the locate() function. Otherwise, clicking on the "Erkunden" button triggers the scope.setData() function even tho both buttons are defined similar.

Pretty sure that it is some stupid error I can not see in my tunnel vision but I just cant solve that issue.

Thanks for your help in advance, best regards 
jule

Comment: I don't see the error in entire code only this one: `</br>` should be `<br />`

Comment: Your AngularJS directive is misspelled as 'ng-Click'.  Correct spelling is 'ng-click'.

Comment: @MoMo or ngClick :)

Comment: Okay, so the solution was neither "ng-click" nor "ngClick". I was alerted when I clicked on the button the <input> was triggered and ready for input so I moved the <button> outside the <label> and now it works. Guess it was some nesting problem with <label>.. 
Anyway, thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work perfectly if you take the button outside the scope of the label.

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
  <span class="input-label">Startpunkt in Adressform</span>
  <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Startpunkt in Adressform">
</label>
<button id="curr_loc" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="locate()">this-one-doesnt-fire</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AngularJS directive is misspelled as 'ng-Click'. Correct spelling is 'ng-click'